# Android: How to have data passed to an interface, maybe used as a parameter

Tags: android, kotlin, interface, retrofit

I want to use `movieId` in the `@GET()` but the thing is I want to use a different variable each time.

I have this interface file, and I am calling it in MainActivity for retrofit. I have tried to () after the interface's name, to pass the data as a parameter, but it doesn't work.
What should I do?

```
interface MovieRecommendationsApiInterface {
    @GET("xxxxxxx")
    fun getRecommendationsList(): Call<MovieResponse>
}
```

Comment: Why don't you go for different methods for different variables?

Comment: I have a recycler view of 30 movies, and each movie has a unique Id, don't think creating a unique interview for every movie is the best choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass movie id. You can modify your method this way.

```
@GET("movies/{id}")
fun getRecommendationsList(@Path("id") id: Int?): Call<MovieResponse>
```